# This print function cannot output the value in the deque

Tags: c++

The result of the current execution of this program does not display the result. I want to display the values in the even deque and odd deque through the print function. During the debugging process, I found that the value in the deque already exists, but the print function will end in the middle.

````
#include <list>
#include <deque>
void print(std::deque<int>::iterator beg, std::deque<int>::iterator end);
int main()
{
    std::list<int> lint{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9};
    std::list<int>::iterator itor;
    std::deque<int> dint1, dint2;
    itor = lint.begin();
    for (; itor != lint.end(); itor++)
    {
        if (*itor % 2 == 0)
        {
            dint2.push_back(*itor);
        }
        else
            dint1.push_back(*itor);
    }
    std::deque<int>::iterator itorde1;
    std::deque<int>::iterator itorde2;
    itorde1 = dint1.begin();
    itorde2 = dint1.end();
    std::deque<int>::iterator itorde3;
    std::deque<int>::iterator itorde4;
    itorde3 = dint2.begin();
    itorde4 = dint2.end();
    print(itorde1, itorde2);
    print(itorde3, itorde4);
   
}
void print(std::deque<int>::iterator beg, std::deque<int>::iterator end){
    while (beg == end)
    {
        std::cout<< *beg;
        beg++;
    }
    
} ```
````

Comment: Please try to explain `while (beg == end)` to your [rubber duck](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging).

Comment: End the loop when the iterator beg is equal to the tail of the deque

Comment: Sorry, I misremembered the condition of the while loop

Comment: Logic error, ITYM `while (beg != end)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have an error in the `print` function, the condition should be `beg != end`.
Here is the function:

```
void print(std::deque<int>::iterator beg, std::deque<int>::iterator end){
    while (beg != end)
    {
        std::cout << *beg;
        beg++;
    }
    std::cout << "\n";
}
```